# how to change marker size on onCameraMove in GoogleMap flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
GoogleMap(
    minMaxZoomPreference: MinMaxZoomPreference(null, ctrl.zoomLevel + 4),
    zoomControlsEnabled: false,
    zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
    myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
    mapType: MapType.normal,
    onMapCreated: (mapCtrl) {
      ctrl.mapController = mapCtrl;
      ctrl.update();
      ctrl.navigateMapToCurrentLocation();
    },
    onCameraMove: (zoom) {
      changeMarkerSizeOnZoom(zoom);//I want to change the marker size on zoom
    },
    initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
      target: ctrl.latLong,
      zoom: ctrl.zoomLevel,
    ),
    markers: ctrl.jobMarkers,
    circles: ctrl.circles,
  )
```

How I can change marker size on zoom in Google map in Flutter
I want to reduce the marker size when the marker zoom-out and the marker side should be big when I zoom on a particular location like the Google map app on Android devices

I have tried a lot but have not found a proper solution for this
i you have done this before please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

1. Define Marker Bitmap Descriptor:

```dart
final BitmapDescriptor customMarker =
  await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(ImageConfiguration(size: Size(48, 48)), 'assets/custom_marker.png');
```

2. Update Marker Icon on Zoom:

```dart
void changeMarkerSizeOnZoom(double zoom) {
  if (ctrl.mapController != null) {
    double scaleFactor = zoom / ctrl.zoomLevel;

    if (scaleFactor < 1) {
      scaleFactor = 1;
    }
    
    ctrl.jobMarkers.forEach((marker) {
      marker.setIcon(customMarker.copyWith(size: Size(48 * scaleFactor, 48 * scaleFactor)));
    });
  }
}
```

3. Call `changeMarkerSizeOnZoom` in `onCameraMove`:

```dart
onCameraMove: (CameraPosition position) =>
  changeMarkerSizeOnZoom(position.zoom);
```